# Laravel url_title helper

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a Laravel 4 equivalent to the codeigniter url_title() function? Or should I just copy it over?

For reference this is the codeigniter one:

```
function url_title($str, $separator = '-', $lowercase = FALSE)
{
    if ($separator == 'dash') 
    {
        $separator = '-';
    }
    else if ($separator == 'underscore')
    {
        $separator = '_';
    }

    $q_separator = preg_quote($separator);

    $trans = array(
        '&.+?;'                 => '',
        '[^a-z0-9 _-]'          => '',
        '\s+'                   => $separator,
        '('.$q_separator.')+'   => $separator
    );

    $str = strip_tags($str);

    foreach ($trans as $key => $val)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
    }

    if ($lowercase === TRUE)
    {
        $str = strtolower($str);
    }

    return trim($str, $separator);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I would vote for using something little better adjusted to your need and laravel itself https://github.com/MattHans0n/slug

how to use packages you could read on that page http://laravel.com/docs/packages